# I have a problem with the following JavaScript code & WordPress, is there a way to run the following JavaScript code inside of WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});
```

I am trying to build a special control panel based on WordPress, but I am having trouble activating the JavaScript code for this template.
The following template was adopted:
https://codepen.io/azouaoui-med/pen/wpBadb

I am a beginner, I have tried in many ways but it has been unsuccessful, please help

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of what you want to achieve with this code and what do you mean about "activating the code for this template" ?

Comment: Where are you placing this code?